# Getting a JSON HTTP POST request from WCF

Tags: android, rest

I write a simple WCF webservice for response to client.
In my simple app on android I write these codes to connect my web service:

```
    private class SetUserFromServerToRv extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        String line = "";

        try {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            URL url = new URL("http://localhost/WcfService_myChat/Service1.svc/json/AllUserQuery");
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
            connection.setReadTimeout(150000);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            connection.connect();

            InputStream response = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response,"utf-8"));
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
            }
            connection.disconnect();
            reader.close();


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return line;
    }
}
```

im manifest i added this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

when I debug my code i got this error:

```
failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 80) after 10000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
```

I tried with this :

```
                URL url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2:8080/WcfService_myChat/Service1.svc/json/AllUserQuery");
```

but i still got error.

by postman I get right answer.

I test my code on my mobile .where is my mistake?thnks

*********Edit**************

I try with my local IP:

```
URL url = new URL("http://192.168.x.x/WcfService_myChat/Service1.svc/json/AllUserQuery");
```

but got this error:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /192.168.100.19 (port 80) after 10000ms
```

Comment: @NMathur  i got this : The server at 10.0.2.2 is taking too long to respond.

Comment: which server are you using?

Comment: @AbdulKawee my server is on my local.

Comment: its wamp or xamp?, there might be possibility that either they are not running or there is some problem with their configuration

Comment: @AbdulKawee when using of Vs (Visual studio) and write a WSF web service .VS itself used of IIS express. but I think my problem is related to android side because postman got right answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if your System and server are in local LAN then it will work because
>   it will found that server but when u trying to get same server from
>   mobile data it will not found because by using mobile data u are searching
>   this IP in WWW but your server IP is Local, so you ave to connect your
>   device with your local LAN WI-FI to get response in mobile.

Comment: if you found its a right answer then u can mark it as right flag also it will help to other users to get right answer.